# Is it possible to run discovery AWS Cognito OIDC IdP before creating via command line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, federated-identity

On the AWS Cognito OIDC IdP page it is possible to `Run Discovery` before creating the provider:

[image]

Is there a way to this via the command line?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do it with the AWS CLI, but you can just call the provider directly with, for example, curl. I just create a test OIDC application on auth0:

```
curl https://example.auth0.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

```
{
  "issuer":"https://example.auth0.com/",
  "authorization_endpoint":"https://example.auth0.com/authorize",
  "token_endpoint":"https://example.auth0.com/oauth/token",
  "device_authorization_endpoint":"https://example.auth0.com/oauth/device/code",
  "userinfo_endpoint":"https://example.auth0.com/userinfo",
  "mfa_challenge_endpoint":"https://example.auth0.com/mfa/challenge",
  "jwks_uri":"https://example.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json",
  "registration_endpoint":"https://example.auth0.com/oidc/register",
  "revocation_endpoint":"https://example.auth0.com/oauth/revoke",
  "scopes_supported":[
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "offline_access",
    "name",
    "given_name",
    "family_name",
    "nickname",
    "email",
    "email_verified",
    "picture",
    "created_at",
    "identities",
    "phone",
    "address"
  ],
  "response_types_supported":[
    "code",
    "token",
    "id_token",
    "code token",
    "code id_token",
    "token id_token",
    "code token id_token"
  ],
  "code_challenge_methods_supported":[
    "S256",
    "plain"
  ],
  "response_modes_supported":[
    "query",
    "fragment",
    "form_post"
  ],
  "subject_types_supported":[
    "public"
  ],
  "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported":[
    "HS256",
    "RS256"
  ],
  "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported":[
    "client_secret_basic",
    "client_secret_post"
  ],
  "claims_supported":[
    "aud",
    "auth_time",
    "created_at",
    "email",
    "email_verified",
    "exp",
    "family_name",
    "given_name",
    "iat",
    "identities",
    "iss",
    "name",
    "nickname",
    "phone_number",
    "picture",
    "sub"
  ],
  "request_uri_parameter_supported":false
}
```

The `.well-known/openid-configuration` path is part of the OIDC protocol and must be defined and return a correct JSON document.